# Which is the more appropriate term: graphics assistance or graphic assistance?

Tags: word-choice

When referring to graphics (Art and Media), can I choose to use both "graphics assistance" and "graphic assistance" or is only the former the more appropriate choice?

She would like to thank Zepo for graphics assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While, yes, "graphics" is the plural of "graphic", you can't assume this is the only meaning of the word.

> [**graphic** (adj)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/graphic_1):  *1. vividly or clearly described, 2. sexually explicit, 3. of or relating to writing or other inscribed representations*

"Graphic assistance" has unintended connotations.  I'm not sure *what*, exactly, it would mean, but it doesn't sound good. Few would misunderstand you, but if you want to say, "assistance with the preparation of these *graphical images*" then, **graphics** assistance is what you want to use.

> I wouldn't have been able to get my website up as quickly without **graphics help** from my wife, the artist.

In cases like this, it may be better to clearly say what you mean:

> I wouldn't have been able to get my website together without my wife's **help with the graphics.**